# Use Docker DNS to redirect all wildcard subdomains to docker nginx

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, dns

I have a Docker setup using nginx on port 80 for my app. I added `my-app.local 127.0.0.1` to my `/etc/hosts` so `http://my-app.local` connects to nginx.

Now, I want all subdomains like `http://random-guid-123.my-app.local` to work with my Docker nginx without adding each one to the hosts file.

I tried using `andyshinn/dnsmasq:latest` with this command:

```
command: --no-daemon --address=/my-app.local/127.0.0.1 --server=8.8.8.8 --server=8.8.4.4
```

But my stack won't start because `systemd-resolve` is already using port 53. I could change my Docker DNS port to 5353, but I don't know how to make `systemd-resolve` listen on that port too. I'm also unsure if this is the right approach.